# Declaring variables in VBA

Tags: vba

```
Dim x, y as Date
```

What is the difference between these two code statements

```
Dim x as Date, y as Date
```

What is the pragmatic result of the difference and what other hidden declaration features am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim x, y as Date
```

is the equivalent of:

```
Dim x 
Dim y as Date
```

and that is the equivalent of:

```
Dim x as Variant
Dim y as Date
```

When you omit the type for a variable, it assumes the `Variant` type

Edit, per your question:

```
Dim a! ' same as Dim a as Short
Dim b@ ' same as Dim b as Currency
Dim c# ' same as Dim c as Double
Dim d$ ' same as Dim d as String
Dim e% ' same as Dim e as Integer
Dim f& ' same as Dim f as Long
```

ref: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/643371-declaration-shortcuts

Comment: So using the comma is not really much of a shortcut as I thought it was. Is there any shortcuts to initialize a variable in the dim statement? I have seen the use of colons and such which I usually do not use.

Comment: There are also the `Def` statements; `DefSng A-Z` makes variables named A to Z of type `Single`.  However this is horrible and can be used to justify homicide.

Comment: I didn't know about those, indeed murderous

Comment: @CodeCamper I'd give up looking for shortcuts, aside from those shorthand notations listed above (e.g., `Dim s$` is equivalent to `Dim s as String`).  It's good practice and makes more legible, maintainable code to put each variable declaration on its own line, and to type them as strongly as circumstances allow.

Comment: @DavidZemens For legibility I usually like to declare a variables contents on the same line I declare them in other languages. Is there any shortcuts to do this? I definitely will be making use of these shortcuts.

Comment: @CodeCamper I made another answer since it would be too long to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim x, y as Date
```

`As <Type>` is required for *each* variable, so in the example above only `y` is a `Date`; `x` is a `Variant` (The default when no type is specified)

```
Dim x as Date, y as Date
```

Both variables are `Dates` as each has an `As`.

Comment: Is there a documentation page somewhere on all the syntactical sugar of Dim in VBA including initializing variables in the Dim? For example I assumed both would be date until I saw the tool tip tell me it was a variant. Also if I declare something as a variant what is the actual difference in programming reality beside the fact that the assist pop up no longer functions?

Comment: Variants break the principle of strong typing; If you had a `date_of_birth` variable you could assign anything to it (a number, a string, an object ref) if it were a `variant`, if it were a `Date` however you know for sure that whatever value it has is a valid date, you never need to check.  Variants are also less performant than typed variables.

Comment: `Dim` statement on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251750%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Semantics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you Alex, DefVar A-AZ is my new best friend. I never have to declare a variable again! If I understand correctly this will actually declare 128255 variants? How useful!

Comment: @CodeCamper heed Alex's comment: *However this (Def statements) is horrible and can be used to justify homicide*. I think you are grossly overestimating how "useful" it will be, explicit declaration is almost always better than implicit.  You might want to read up on it, because I don't think it works the way you think it does: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263421(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 3):

> For legibility I usually like to declare a variables contents on the same line I declare them in other languages. Is there any shortcuts to do this?

For `Constant` expressions, yes:

```
Const i as Integer = 6
Const myName as String = "David Zemens"
```

For dynamic variables, it's not possible without using the colon, i.e., `Dim i as Integer: i = 6` but the colon is actually interpreted like a line-break, so there's no real advantage to doing so.

And while assigning simple values known at design time can be done this way, if you look around you'll see this is simply not often-used in VBA programming. Instead, you typically will see **ALL** declarations at the top of module/procedure, followed by assignment statements for those variables which need an initial value. All other assignments happen during run-time at the point in the code where an assignment needs to be made or changed

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim x as Date
Dim y as Date

i = 1
x = DateValue(Now())

y = DateAdd("d", i, x)

MsgBox y
```

Compare the following:

```
Dim i as Integer: i = 6
```

Simple enough, right? But what about:

```
Dim i as Integer: i = SomeFunction(arg1, arg2, obj.Property1)
```

The above will work, but of course **ONLY** if the arguments for the function are assigned prior to this declaration, any object variables are instantiated, etc.

What I'm saying is that while there are some cases where you *could* do this, in the vast majority of cases it's simply not practical to do so, and for consistency's sake, I would personally recommend against that sort of in-line declaration & assignment.

Answer (score -1):

```
    Dim x, y as Date
'Is the same as:
    Dim x as Variant
    Dim y as Date
```

Now

```
    Dim x as Date, y as Date
'Is the same as:
    Dim x as Date
    Dim y as Date
```

If you don't declare the data type for a VBA variable, VBA uses Variant (the default data type)

Comment: Was there really a need to post the same information as in already existing answers, posted six years prior?