# count items based on columns in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to use vba to write countifs function but got an error of object doesn't support this property or method. (Run-time error 438)

```
Sub counters()

    Dim rng, rng2, rng3, rng4 As Range
    Dim lrow, lr, lr2, lr3, lr4 As Long
    Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Table E-1 Zip Codes PIF")

    lr = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    lr3 = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
    lr4 = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row
    lrow = ws1.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    'zip code
    Set rng = ws.Range("D2:D" & lr)
    'county
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("X2:X" & lr2)
    'Region
    Set rng3 = ws.Range("Y2:Y" & lr3)
    'policy form
    Set rng4 = ws.Range("AE2:AE" & lr4)

For i = 5 To lrow - 1
Worksheets("Table E-1 Zip Codes PIF").Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ws.rng, ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value, ws.rng2, ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value, ws.rng3, "NW", ws.rng4, "Basic Choice")
Next i

End Sub
```

Excel function works fine but need to use vba to automate the process. Tried recording the macro but it gives reference and wasn't sure how to re-write codes for ranges (ws.Range("x2:x" & lr)). All of the rng have the same amount of data (rows) so wasn't sure if I need to define it each time.

I want my result to be from D5 to N-1 in Table E-1... sheet. I used For i = 5 To lrow - 1 since there is a total in the last row.

In Table E-1 sheet, Column D have a list of zip codes and column E have a list of county that I am trying to match.

Comment: `ws.rng` is invalid syntax. just use `rng` as that is already a defined range object (which the formula expects as an argument). fix all instances like that. *n.b. - you could also change it to `ws.Range(rng.Address)` but its clunkier

Comment: You need to look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238292/declaring-variables-in-vba) about declaring variables.

Comment: Thanks Scott and Rdster, I will read about how to properly declaring variables and I was able to fix my codes and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Except for how you use your `CountIfs` Function, since there are no screen-shots of your data, the code below will take care of your run-time errors.

Explanation for your run-time errors:

1.Wrong declaration, `Dim ws, ws1 As Worksheet` should be `Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet` , otherwise `ws` is not defined as `Worksheet`. The same goes to all of your variables declarations.

2.Find last row in a column: `lr = ws.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row` is wrong, it should be `lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row`.

3.Like @Scott Holtzman wrote in his comment, since you already set your `rng` in previous lines, (`Set rng = ws.Range("D2:D" & lr)`) , then  it should be used with just `rng` and not `ws.rng`.

4.To improve and clean your code, you could just use `With ws` in the beginning of your code, and nest most of it related objects underneath.

### "Clean" Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub counters()

Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range
Dim lrow As Long, lr As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long, lr4 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Data")
Set ws1 = Sheets("Table E-1 Zip Codes PIF")

' last row in Column B in "Table E-1 Zip Codes PIF" sheet
lrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

With ws
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
    lr3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Y").End(xlUp).Row
    lr4 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AE").End(xlUp).Row

    'zip code
    Set rng = .Range("D2:D" & lr)
    'county
    Set rng2 = .Range("X2:X" & lr2)
    'Region
    Set rng3 = .Range("Y2:Y" & lr3)
    'policy form
    Set rng4 = .Range("AE2:AE" & lr4)

    For i = 5 To lrow - 1
        ws1.Cells(i, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value, rng2, ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value, rng3, "NW", rng4, "Basic Choice")
    Next i

End With

End Sub
```