# Macro for unlocking Views in Catia not working

Tags: vba, catia

I'm trying to create macro for Catia V5 that will automaticly unlock all views and update them. Macro updates all the views(when they are unlocked).
Problem is it only unlocks views on sheet that i was currently at before running macro and then it wont update other views on other sheets.

So Unlocking of views will work only on Drawing Sheet that i had active last before running my macro.
But if all of my views are unlocked and i run the macro it will update all of my views, but for some reason unlocking them when i have them locked wont work as previously stated above.

```
Sub CATMain()

Dim oDrawing As DrawingRoot
Dim oViews As DrawingViews
Dim oSheets As DrawingSheets

Set oDrawing = CATIA.ActiveDocument.DrawingRoot
Set oSheets = oDrawing.Sheets
Set oViews = oDrawing.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views

Dim i, y As Integer

For y = 1 To oSheets.Count
    oDrawing.Sheets.Item(y).Activate
    For i = 1 To oViews.Count
        oViews.Item(i).LockStatus = False
    oDrawing.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Update
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

I expect from my macro to unlock all views and update them on each sheet of drawing.

Comment: Do `i` and `y` count to the expected numbers? Maybe consider a `For Each` Loop instead of a counter based iteration. You can "watch" the variable by using right-click add watch, or you can use `debug.print "y: " & y, "i: " & i`

Comment: Also: `i` is declared as a `Variant` in your case. See this question for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238292/declaring-variables-in-vba

Comment: `oView` is set outside of the first `For` loop. You should set it inside. Currently you only modify the views of the initaly active sheet. Changing the active sheet after setting the variable won't adjust the variable.

Comment: @VincentG thanks that solved my problem. I see that oViews was defined before loop (my active sheet with views). But thought loop command right after first ''for y'' would change that, i guess not.

Comment: @L8n Thanks for help and extra guidance, didn't know about declaration of variables thingy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not using Catia, but your code should look like this:

```
Sub CATMain()

    Dim oDrawing As DrawingRoot
    Dim oView As DrawingView
    Dim oSheet As DrawingSheet
    Set oDrawing = CATIA.ActiveDocument.DrawingRoot

    For Each oSheet in oDrawing.Sheets
       For Each oView in oSheet.Views
          oView.LockStatus = False
          oSheet.Update 'Not sure if required here, might be moved outside the loop?
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of just `Next` I prefer to write `Next oView` (for example). It adds some additional clarification. In small loops as it is the case here it does not really matter, but it can help when the code starts to "grow".

Comment: This is what worked for me best, thanks for help.


    `For y = 1 To oSheets.Count
        oDrawing.Sheets.Item(y).Activate
        Set oViews = oDrawing.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Views
        For i = 1 To oViews.Count
            oViews.Item(i).LockStatus = False
        Next i
    oDrawing.Sheets.ActiveSheet.Update
    Next y`